# Radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^{n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Let $\sum a_n x^n$ be a power series with radius of convergence $R$.

What is the radius of convergence of $\sum a_n x^{n^2}$?

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Do you know the formula with $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}$? Use it for the second series. The indices with zero coefficients can be ignored for the computations of $\limsup$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $b_k:=a_n$ if $k=n^2$ and $b_k:=0$ else.

Comment: and now i use weierstrass test?

Comment: Well, I thought about the formula with $\limsup$, commented by @WeaponofChoice.